# Clicking on an image link, page keeps refreshing

Tags: website, hyperlink

I have 4 links setup the same exact way, except for the obvious part that they each go to different websites. And instead of clicking on a hyperlink, it is an image. 3 of the 4 are working just fine, except for the 4th. When it is clicked on, the page loads up but then keeps refreshing over and over again. After a few attempts of clicking on stop, it will finally quit. The only other difference is that this link is to a website that we have internally, but was working before until we did a recent upgrade on our main host system. **What would cause this and how can I fix it?** Below is an example of the link, just changing the HREF for confidentiality purposes.

```
 PRINT "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF VALIGN=center HALIGN=BOTTOM>"
 NEWLINE
 PRINT "<A HREF='http://myserver/thetarget/' target='NEW_page4'>"
 NEWLINE
 PRINT "<img SRC='jmfa.jpg'"
 NEWLINE
 PRINT "border=0 alt='John Doe'></a></TD>"
 NEWLINE
```

**Correction:** I thought this was happening only after our update to our main host, but was able to go back into our old host database and duplicate the same problem.

Comment: The HTML code looks fine. Can you visit `http://myserver/thetarget/` directly from the address bar? If not, you probably have a redirect loop.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, if I open a browser and manually type in the target link, it comes up just fine.

Comment: Still, I fail to see how the linking page could be at fault. There must be some redirect loop or auto-refresh, possibly referer-dependent. Without being able to visit the site and/or see the source code (if it's dynamically generated), it will be quite difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the target='NEW_page4' to target='_blank'

Not sure why it would have caused this problem since other links were setup the same way, but I was able to fix it!